# Generic Japanese greeting new people?

Tags: nuances, colloquial-language, word-requests, formality, greetings

The most commonly cited one is Konnichiwa, but knowing that is time specific, can it be used generically in all hours of the day as a "hello" instead of a specific "good afternoon"? Ohayou and Konbanwa doesn't seem to hold the same nuance to me as a standard greeting and more of greeting your coworkers or friends in the morning/evening.

Any generic greetings like these informal greetings such as 'domo' or 'osu' or 'ya/yo'?

Comment: Why not say 初めて

Comment: ^Tom, You mean 「初めまして」?

Answer (score 1):

Domo and yo works (osu sounds weird unless you are both in a martial arts club. Ya as an informal greeting is archaic). You can also use ou.